# DateBox custom class

Tags: c#, class, custom-controls

I want to create a custom class that I enter / display the date. The problem is that I created it in VFP without problems, but in C# did not know where to start.
In VFP I created a container class in which I placed a label that lists first 3 letters of the day, and another 3 objects of type textbox each for day, month and year. Each textbox has code that pressing the up arrow on your keyboard to increment the value and pressing the down arrow to decrement the value. Each textbox has the ability to make blue (select entire length of the text) when it takes focus.
In VFP exists Class Browser, wich open a class library (.vcx) and allow you to drag and drop classes to forms (custom classes).

First instance has the first tab stop. When form is launched the lcDay object (first textbox of my datebox class) takes the focus and selects all text in it. When the textbox1 (lnDay) is filled it gives the focus automatically to textbox2 (lnMonth), selecting all the text inside, and so on. If the date is ok (verified with function date(year,month,day), in my case the code for verification is in a custom method of container class, named "verificare" and check if date(lnYear,lnMonth,lcDay) is not empty) i call another custom method which change the orange label caption to the first three letters of date().

Can i make such a custom class and use it in my C# forms?

The image for my VFP class:

[image: Existing VFP solution]

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C Sharp".

Comment: Can you tell us which presentation framework you want to use? WinForms? WPF? WebForms?

Comment: Just from curiosity: VFP = Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9.0 ?

Comment: Most GUI frameworks already have a DatePicker. Otherwise, look for UserControl.

Comment: @YannickBlondeau I want to use WinForms.

Comment: @AdrianCiura - Da Adrian, este Visual FoxPro 9.0

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't want to use DatePicker, it's a timeless solution.

Comment: |DatePicker is very configurable. You can omit the Time part.

Comment: In short, yes you can build this control, but it would be much too large for this forum. Follow @HenkHolterman advice, and leverage the `DatePicker` and configure the control. ***It will not work like Visual FoxPro***, trust me, I remember coming from VFP and thinking how much I hated the controls in .NET - but believe me - it will be okay. You'll get used to them, and their properties, and you'll start understanding why they work the way they work.

Comment: Thank you @HenkHolterman, i want to look something like my picture. I put a DatePicker object on my form, i set CustomFormat to ddd dd/MM/yyyy and set Format to Custom. It worked! Thanks. Can i save it as a custom class? How can i change CultureInfo to show "ddd" day in romanian language?

Comment: i saw that when i change day from keyboard it reselect the day. Can i put some code to focus on month and after that in year box?

Comment: I have a problem. I've setup the maxdate value of the DateTimePicker to 31/12/2030. In realtime when i click on the top left icon of the DateTimePicker the control block itself for awhile and after it changes the page to previews month the date it set automatically to maxdate value. If i set the max date to a greater date (ex. 31/12/2100) the control blocks itself for 5-6 seconds. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide which User Interface framework you want to use in C#. I guess you want to create a Desktop application. You can choose from 2 most often used frameworks from Microsoft:

- Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) - the newest framework (e.g. used for the Win8 Modern apps)
- Windows Forms (System.Windows.Forms namespace)
- There are also other options less popular (GtkSharp, Silverlight, etc)

In C# you can use a Date picker control that can be customized to suit your needs:

- Here is a tutorial for WinForms [DateTimePicker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetimepicker)
- WPF's [DatePicker tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-datepicker/)

Comment: How can i check programatically when day is inserted from keyboard to switch cursor to month, and how can i do this?!

Comment: I found the answer! ValueChanged event!